# Change height of react-native-screens navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-screens

Is it possible to change the height (or add a padding to its content) of a `react-native-screens/native-stack` header? The default react navigation header has different style properties (such as height) than the native one has. The action buttons on the right should have a few px space to the bottom of the header when the header is collapsed (content scrolled).

[image]

Comment: post the minimum reproducible code which is causing the issue.

Comment: @KetanRamteke There is no issue as such, and the navigation is just created using the default code (`const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamsList>();`) and `<RootStack.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />`. This is more a general question if it's possible to achieve this and no code is necessary/helpful.